# Why bother with the "L" in the "LVHA" link styles?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Isn't the "a:link" pseudoclass redundant with "a" when put in that order (:link, :visited, :hover, :active)? Why put this:

```
a:link {color: blue;}
a:visited {color: purple;}
a:hover {color: red;}
a:active {color: yellow;}
```

When you could just put this:

```
a {color: blue;}
a:visited {color: purple;}
a:hover {color: red;}
a:active {color: yellow;}
```

I ask because the first one is the most common example I see of the LVHA order. The second version has the same specificity, so it functions the same way. Is it just an organizational thing to make clear what's changing when the link state changes? What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not all anchor tags necessarily have a `href` attribute, so they're not all links. Presumably the `:link` pseudoclass does not apply to anchor tags without a `href`.

Comment: <a>'s without href's are often javascript hooks.

Comment: Or anchors for old browsers, `<a name="anchor"/>`

Comment: I did a quick test, and that is indeed the case. The `link` pseudoclass doesn't apply to anchor tags without a `href`.

Answer (score 4):

The [pseudo-classes `:link` and `:visited`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) are only for links (`A` elements with an `href` attribute):

> - The :link pseudo-class applies for links that have not yet been visited.
> - The :visited pseudo-class applies once the link has been visited by the user.
>
> […]
>
> The document language determines which elements are hyperlink source anchors. For example, in HTML4, the link pseudo-classes apply to A elements with an "href" attribute.

But the [pseudo-classes `:hover`, `:active` and `:focus`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) are not just for links but can also be applied on other elements like `input` or `textarea`.

So to be correct and only select `A` elements that actually are links, you would need to use `a:link`. And to select only links that are hovered, you would need to use `a:link:hover` and not just `a:hover`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the diff v. :link and :link:hover.  http://jsbin.com/iyuyo/edit

Answer (score 3):

According to the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes):

> The :link pseudo-class applies for links that have not yet been visited.

:link allows you to style unvisited links while leaving other link styles unaffected.

Comment: Unvisited links are also styled by a{...}

Comment: Sure, but a { ... } changes the style for all pseudo classes. Just "a {color: red}" would make visited, unvisited, hover and active links appear with red foreground color, while "a:link {color: red}" would only make unvisited links appear with red forground color.

Comment: But the question is specific to the other 3 states being defined too.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `a` does not affect any pseudo-class states (since all it is is a type selector!). It's only when you specify styles for the various pseudo-classes that they override any generic `a` rules. Also, `a:hover` and `a:active` can pick up `a:link` styles as well, as they're not mutually exclusive - that only affects `a:visited`. In other words, any link can be `a:link:hover` or `a:link:active`, or even `a:link:hover:active`, but not `a:link:visited`.